# How to calculate the curvature (arc) of a circle around a sphere?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, astronomy

I would like to draw a circle representing the moon, and over this circle draw an arc representing the sun's illumination for each percentage of illumination.
Although the image of this moon is in 2D I need the arc to have a "realism" in its curvature.
I would like a function that receives a parameter as a percentage of illumination (eg: 27%) and returns the drawing of the arc with the correct curvature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moon terminator is an **elliptical arc** with *vertical* axis being constant (equals to Moon diameter) while *horizontal* axis changes linear with Moon `phase` which is

```
   0 - New Moon
0.25 - First Quarter
0.50 - Full Moon
0.75 - Last Quarter
```

**Bitmap** creation to show the idea:

```
private static Bitmap DrawMoon(int radius, float phase) {
  phase = (phase % 1 + 1) % 1;

  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(2 * radius, 2 * radius);

  var rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 2 * radius - 20, 2 * radius - 20);

  float w = Math.Abs(rect.Width - rect.Width * (4 * phase % 2));

  // Terminator is elliptical, verical axis is constant
  // While horizontal change as linear function from phase
  var term = new RectangleF(
    rect.Left + (rect.Width - w) / 2, rect.Top, w, rect.Height);

  // Width == 10 to exagerate the lines, to show they are elliptical
  using var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Yellow, 10);

  using (Graphics gs = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
    gs.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));

    if (phase > 0.5f)
      gs.DrawArc(pen, rect, 90, 180);
    else
      gs.DrawArc(pen, rect, -90, 180);

    if (phase < 0.25f || phase > 0.5 && phase < 0.75)
      gs.DrawArc(pen, term, -90, 180);
    else
      gs.DrawArc(pen, term, 90, 180);
  }

  return image;
}
```

Several Moon phases (**0.12**, **0.27**, **0.54**, **0.95**):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you insist on *per cent of illumination* you should solve an *equation*. Moon illumination is an area of the half of the Moon plus or minus half of the ellipse, for instance for phases `[0..0.25]`

```
illumination = pi * R * R / 2 - pi * R * R * (0.5 - 2 * phase)
```

so for the New Moon we have `illumination == 0` and for the 1st Quarter `illumination == pi * R * R / 2`

Comment: thanks Dmitry! Your answer will really help me a lot, thank you for your kindness in writing such a detailed answer.

Comment: @Sarcastic Bender: You are welcome! I am an amateur astronomer then :)